Gravitational lensing self-reconstruction of original image?
I'm not familiar enough with gravitational lensing to tell if this is a dumb idea or not. I know the general concept - a sufficiently large mass in between the observer and the source distorts both its position and its shape, 'smearing' it either into a circle around the massive object or an arc-segment if misaligned.
My question is - if you had many (thousands? Millions?) of individual objects of very small angular size relative to the source, all gravitationally lensing a single source relative to the observer, could the light coming off of each be cumulatively shaped like the original object? In other words, if you had enough gravitational lenses on the same image, could each individual distortion be accumulated into an overall reconstruction of the image?
The thought behind this question is mostly worldbuilding for a story - I'm exploring ways a spaceship could 'appear' larger than it actually is from the reference point of an external observer, but otherwise remain visually undistorted.

tldr: is this a Fresnel Gravity Lens?

Yes, this is possible in theory.
Although it’s virtually impossible to actually state such a system of bodies that reconstructs the original image, there isn’t a reason it can’t happen. It would probably be something like a field of black holes set in a pattern so that geodesics end up parallel after passing the initial body (that originally distorted the image) parallel. It would be an extremely complex system and I can’t say what exactly it would look like, but I can say with certainty that it exists. Expect some level of distortion if this is to happen naturally; nature is far from perfect.
For the record, this wouldn’t make the image clearer or brighter. By brightness, it would still seem as far away as it is (actually farther since the light is traveling a greater distance), and given the fact that the object distant enough to be gravitationally lensed it’s either extremely bright or very, very large. Keep that in mind.
